# What is special about the area 30 km west of Beijing?

Tags: china, beijing

A geocaching map of the Beijing area, shows an unusual pattern:

[image]

Almost all the geocache sites (green circles) are clustered in an area 30 km or so to the west of Beijing, with almost no sites in the capital itself or other surrounding territory.

What is so special, either from a native or tourist perspective, about this area that would cause this phenomenon?

Comment: Did you check some of the caches to see if they were made by the same user?

Comment: I'm not saying this is off-topic, but I suspect you'd be much more likely to find an answer on a geocaching-specific forum than here.

Comment: @ChrisH, I'm not so concerned about geocaching itself. That's only an obvious symptom. It's the underlying cause that I'm wondering about.

Comment: Also, I think Geocaching shows just the first X caches on the map, so there might be more out there, they are just not visible.

Comment: All you're seeing is that that map system happens to draw the label "Beijing" in the "wrong" spot.  (Not the actual "real" city center.)  There's nothing more to it than that.

Comment: For a second I misinterpreted the question. I thought you were asking what was so special on the West of Beijing that everyone would camp there, until I read the answer twice and realised you were wondering why the map is off (initially having the impression the answer wasn't answering the question). Maybe I should get a coffee.

Comment: @Clockwork, no, you were right the first time.  It didn't occur to me that the map might be wrong (what kind of a map would mislocate a country's capital city so badly?). I saw all the interesting points clustered in an area 30 km west of the "Beijing" label and wondered why there weren't any in Beijing itself (e.g. a high security zone might make hiding secret caches and cryptic notes in that area an especially stupid activity).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### The map is correct. Beijing literally is there in the east.

Traditionally, Beijing is the dense area, consists of Xicheng and Dongcheng districts, with Forbidden City in the center. Right inside the 2nd Ring Road (二环路). Every Beijing natives and every tourists still call that the city center of Beijing.

But, in 2019, Beijing municipal government **moved to Tongzhou 通州 District**, a new area specially designed for administration, called "the city's subsidiary center" (城市副中心).

> The Chinese capital has planned for years to shift its administrative
> center out to the outer Tongzhou district in an effort to rein in
> population growth, traffic congestion and air pollution in Beijing’s
> denser inner districts. [Caixin report](https://www.caixinglobal.com/2019-01-11/beijing-city-government-moves-into-new-home-in-outer-district-101369085.html)

Maps are taking different display measure. For example, Baidu Map still shows the old city center at low zooming levels, but if zoom in to Tongzhou District, you would see (the Chinese of) Beijing Municipal Government, quite away from Beijing "Proper":

[image: Baidu map screenshot]

Answers about distortion maps are wrong. There is distortion with maps in China, but that is about 100m, not with 30 km.

Comment: Welcome to [Travel.SE]!  This is a better answer than mine, and I encourage people to upvote it.

Comment: "*Q: Why are standards so wonderful? — A: Because there are so many to choose from.*" ¶ Some maps put a city's label where city hall is located, others put it where the city's downtown (central business district) is.  In this case, city hall moved  to the suburbs, and some maps moved with it and some didn't.

Comment: @RayButterworth Just as a reminder, Beijing CBD means a particular place in Chaoyang District in Beijing near the 3rd Ring Road. It isn't the traditional city center (Forbidden City) either!

Comment: So this answer explains why the label is to the right over there, but as someone not familiar with the area, why are there zero geocaches there? Is it just a place that you typically would not walk around/explore? Perhaps mostly office area?

Comment: @Conor Some of the the geocaches are in tourist hotspots, and others are in areas popular with foreigners and Chinese students, perhaps suggesting that this is mainly a hobby of more cosmopolitan Beijingers. There are hardly any in the working-class residential areas. Tongzhou is neither beautiful nor cosmopolitan....

Comment: @Conor Right, it's basically some office buildings and construction sites. Besides, the move happened in 2019, and for obvious reason there wasn't many tourists visiting since then.

Answer (score 27):

This just looks to be a problem with the labels of the base map used by that geocaching site.  If you look at other online mapping services ([Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/HjwZAShFvzY1JL4r7), [Bing Maps](https://www.bing.com/maps?osid=37018596-3354-4cfa-8ffb-3daae6580547&cp=39.947849%7E116.450772&lvl=10&v=2&sV=2&form=S00027)), they clearly show central Beijing located near the center of the large beltway highway shown in your screenshot.  For example, in your screenshot you can see the thin, squared-off moats surrounding the Forbidden City about 2 km east of the "Xicheng" label.

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with the GPS misalignment stuff certain maps of China suffer from?

Comment: @Jan The maps don't suffer from misalignment, they are distorted as an official policy. See for example [here](https://www.serviceobjects.com/blog/why-gps-coordinates-look-wrong-on-maps-of-china/), but I can verify from personal experience that any mapping products (e.g. car navigation systems) can only be sold in China if you, the developer, send your code to the Chinese authorities, who add their secret distortion algorithm, complie the whole into a binary blob and sign that to approve distribution.

Comment: @zovits Yes, that is what I meant, I just used a wrong word.

Comment: Why Every Map of China is Just Slightly Wrong https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9Di-UVC-_4

Comment: @hojusaram, that's interesting and worthy of a question of its own, but I don't think it applies here, where the discrepancy is 30,000m not just 100m or so.

Comment: There's a lot of a calculations go into deciding where to place map labels. Sometimes these produce odd results, because it is a hard problem. We can see the credits mention "MapTiler" which will be providing "vector tile" map data into this display originally from OpenStreetMap. Could be a snapshot of that changing data caused the problem (in which case it may get fixed), or an issue in a version of the MapBox GL JS front end display system. It's so widely off though I wonder if geocaching.com have tried to add supplementary place names data to "improve" things, causing it to go wrong here.

Comment: @zovits they'd rather the US blast something else than the Embassy... :)

Comment: Right and wrong. Beijing label is there because the municipal government is there. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This most probably has to do with the obfuscation of the geographic coordinates mandated in China, where apparently random offsets are added to them.

See more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China#GCJ-02).

There are open-source, freely available de-obfuscators available on github, which can be integrated with OpenLayers, leaflet, etc. -- I have used them ;-) I say you better report it as a bug to that geocaching site.

Comment: But shouldn't the city-names still be somewhat aligned with the roads, if not with the caches?